# Missing object property value

Tags: php

I want to send some data through a one-way direction using a static method called `send` which send data to an instance of `Module` interface. Then a method which is defined and implemented within abstract class `Module` called `receiver` will assign the sent values to a `data` property  by instantiating the `StorageClass` which converts an array to an object. after assignment, `var_dump` displays available data inside of `data` property correctly and expectably:

```
/home/ahmad/Desktop/Vanilla/src/classes/Module/Module.php:16:
object(Vanilla\Collection\StorageClass)[22]
  protected 'storageContainer' => 
    array (size=1)
      'commentsCount' => int 10
```

But after calling `broadcast` method in a Module Loader which calls broadcast method of every `Module` object, I get:

```
/home/ahmad/Desktop/Vanilla/src/classes/ModuleLoader/ModuleLoader.php:88:null
```

abstract class Module:

```
public $data;
public function receiver($value){
    $this->data = new StorageClass($value);
}

public function broadcast(){
    return null;
}
```

And a module overriding `broadcast`:

```
public function broadcast()
{
    Broadcast::send(new Template(), ['commentsCount' => 10]);
}
```

And finally, the Broadcast class:

```
class Broadcast
{
    public static function send(Module $to, $value){
        $to->receiver($value);
    }
}
```

Also `ModuleLoader` makes an array of modules. Then it calls runBroadcaster method:

```
private function runBroadcasters(){
    foreach ($this->moduleInstancesCollection as $instance){
        $instance->broadcast();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what is in line 88 of ModuleLoader.php?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: Where is `$this->moduleInstancesCollection` defined?

Comment: before calling `runBroadcasters()` there is a call to method `initialModuleInstancesCollection` which constructs `$this->moduleInstancesCollection` and assign instances of required modules (`Module` concrete  implementations) as an array to `$this->moduleInstancesCollection` . Also moduleInstancesCollection is a private property of `ModuleLoader` class.

Comment: And the method `initialModuleInstancesCollection` is inside the same class?

Comment: yes, it is defined in `ModuleLoader` class  which is responsible for instantiating and calling required methods of each `Module` implementation.

Comment: I guess, then you have to go through the class and see at which point the variable becomes null.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that I was passing a new Instance of every module to Broadcast::send() as first argument not an existing one.

Comment: Glad, you could find a solution.